# Prove that the following pairs of linear space are isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra

(a) $\mathbb R^n$ and the collection of all polynomials in a variable $x$ of degree smaller than $n$;

(b) $\mathbb R^{mn}$ and $M(m,n)$;

(c) $\mathbb R^n$ and the $(\mathbb R^n)^T$ ($\mathbb R^n$ transposed)

I tried looking up the definition of isomorphism, however I could not find the conditions under which pairs of linear space are isomorphic. Thus, I also do not know what properties I should prove. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Two finite dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension.

Comment: Thank you David Mitra. I am not sure though how I can prove this. Could you help me on my way with the prove for question a?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: The simplest way to prove two things are isomorphic is to write down an isomorphism between them.

Comment: Yes I do @WaqasAliAzhar.

Comment: @ChrisEagle This sounds very abstract to me, could you show me how this would work for question a?

Comment: If it is $\mathbb R^n$ then considering the canonical basis ${(1,...,0),...,(0,...,1)}$ for it and a basis for second space in (a) is ${1,x,...,x^{n-1}}$.

Comment: I hope you can now see how both the spaces have same dimension, now apply what @DavidMitra said.

Comment: @WaqasAliAzhar Sorry, this does not make much sense to me since I do not have a lot experience in these kind of proves. Could you please be a bit more elaborate? What exactly is a 'canonical basis'?

Comment: What do you know about linear spaces?

Comment: Not much to be honest. I know the definition but that is about where it ends.

Comment: Could you please show me how your suggestions would work for question a? Maybe then I can get the hang of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, two (finite dimensional) vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension. That is they are isomorphic if and only if the number of elements in the bases are the same.

If $V$ is a vector space with basis $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ and $W$ a vector space with basis $\{f_1,\dots , f_n\}$ then the linear map defined by
$$
\phi(e_i) = f_i
$$
is an isomorphism. What does that mean? That means that $\phi$ is bijective and linear. By definition it is linear, so you just have to think about why it is bijective.

So for your examples, you just have to determine the dimensions of the given vector spaces.

For $\mathbb{R}^n$ you can pick as basis $\{e_1, \dots , e_n\}$ where $e_i$is the vector with zeros in all entries except in the $i$th entry where you have a $1$. All this is saying is that the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has dimension $n$.

Now consider the space of polynomials of degree less than $n$. This also happens to be a vector space of degree $n$. Try to look up the definition of a basis and prove that the set $X = \{1, x, x^2, x^3, \dots, x^{n-1}\}$ is a basis. Added: As you have realized this means that you have to prove that the set is linearly independent and that the set spans the whole space.

First: The space of polynomials of degree less than $n$ is the set of elements of the form
$$
a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + \dots + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}
$$
(Where the $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$). But this says exactly that each polynomial is a linear combination of the elements in the set $X$. SO $X$ spans the whole space.

Second: To show linear independence you start by assuming that a linear combination of the elements in the set $X$ is $0$:
$$
a_0 + a_1x + \dots + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} = 0.
$$
Now $0$ is the same as the zero polynomial (as mentioned below in the comment) so we realize $0 = 0 + 0x + \dots + 0x^{n-1}$. But, you might know, two polynomials are equal if and only if the coefficients are the same. That is if the coefficient in front of $x^i$ are the same. So from the above assumption we have the all the $a_i$ are zero. And so we have showed that the set $X$ is linearly independent.

After this, you might be able to guess a basis for $M(m,n)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I think that that means that I have to prove that all elements in {1,x,x2,x3,…,nn} are linear independent, and that they span the entire space? Could you please show me how this is done? I am still not entirely sure how to do this.

Comment: @user48288: Sure, I will update my answer.

Comment: Consider an arbitrary linear combination of {$1,x,...,x^{n-1}$} equals to zero(polynomial). When two polynomials are equal? What is the shape of a general polynomial of degree $n-1$?

Comment: Upon rereading your proof one question came up in my mind. Why does the fact that two vector spaces have the same dimension imply linearity and bijectivity?

Comment: @user48288: It doesn't ... sort of. IF you have two vector spaces with the same dimension, then that means that the number of elements in a basis is the same for both spaces. Then you define $\phi$ as above in the answer: $\phi(e_i) = f_i$. We then extend this "by linearity". That is: defining the map on the basis alone doesn't actually give you a map on the whole space, so you simply define it to be linear. So you define: $$\phi(a_1e_1 + \dots +a_ne_n) = a_1f_1 + \dots a_nf_n$$
So the linearity is in the definition. It is clearly bijective as well (you get every element in $W$).

Comment: Try then to think about why the map is injective.

Answer (score 1):

For Part (a), Choose a basis {$e_1,\dots,e_n$}={$(1,\dots,0),\dots,(0,\dots,1)$} of $\mathbb R^n$ where $e_i$=($0,\dots,1,\dots,0$) i.e 1 at the ith position and zero else where. Similarly as show above a basis for $P_n$ (the space of all polynomials of degree less than $n$) to be {$1,x,...,x^{n-1}$}. Let $\phi$ be the linear map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $P_n$ as $\phi(\alpha e_i)=\alpha x^{i-1} \forall \alpha \in K$, Linearity follows from the fact $\forall \alpha,\beta \in K$ we have $\phi(\alpha v+\beta w)=\phi(\alpha \sum a_ie_i + \beta \sum b_ie_i)=\phi((\sum \alpha a_i+\beta b_i)e_i)=(\sum \alpha a_i+\beta b_i)x^{i-1}=\alpha \phi(v) + \beta \phi(w) \forall v,w \in \mathbb R^n$ Surjectivity is obvious for injectivity let us have a look at the kernel of $\phi$, and it is easy to see that only only $0 \in \mathbb R^n$ maps to zero polynomial under $\phi$ so it is injective as well. Hence $\mathbb R^n \cong P_n$ .

Others are similiar (Try to extend maps from a basis)